# loop through #N/A in a column and insert a formula over all #N/A

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, copy, formula

So I have a column with close to 100k entries. I want to loop through every #N/A in the column and replae the #N/A with a formula. I got the finding of #N/A and the formula- inserting working fine but I seem to have a mistake in my loop, which I don´t get. My Code looks like this

```
Sub Test()
Dim findrow As Double
Dim lstrow As Double
Dim row As Double
Dim length As String
Dim emp As Variant
Dim Err As String

Err = "#N/A"
emp = " "
row = 1
lstrow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row



Workbooks("(Test)").Activate


For row = 1 To lstrow
    If IsError(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("F" & row).Offset(offsetCount, 0).value) Then
        If (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("F1" & row).Offset(offsetCount, 0).value = CVErr(xlErrNA)) Then
            findrow = global_searchByRow_inCol("#N/A", Workbooks("(Test)"), 6)
        End If
    End If
        If Not findrow = 0 Then
            Cells(findrow, 6).formula = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(august.csv!$C:$C,MATCH(R" & findrow & ",august.csv!$D:$D,0)))= TRUE," & emp & ",(INDEX(august.csv!$C:$C,MATCH(R" & findrow & ",august.csv!$D:$D,0))))"
        End If

Next row
```

I get the error `type mismatch` in line

```
If Range("F" & row) = Err Then
```

It´s the correct row but it doens´t execute `Then`. If I debugg and put it one line down manually, it runs perfectly again until the next #N/A. What am I not getting here?

Edit: Error is type mismatch and `offset`is empty

Comment: `If Range("F" & row) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then`

Comment: Not sure, the code runs through, but it doesn´t copy the formula over the #N/A..

Comment: Just edited the Code

Comment: Change `.value <> Err` to `.value  = CVErr(xlErrNA)`

Comment: Then I get an Error again

Comment: On what line and what is the error message?

Comment: The one you told me to change to ```.value  = CVErr(xlErrNA)```

Comment: Why do you have the 1 in `Range("F1" & row)`? That looks like a typo.

Comment: Oh Gosh, yes that was the error. Sorry, for taking so much of your time for such a pathetic error. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
If Range("F" & row).Text = Err Then
```

Use `.Text` instead `.Value` to avoid and error, if you use `.Text`, the range give you just text text inside the range as a string, what ever the range have.

In your version of the line (`If Range("F" & row) = Err Then`) what you are saying is:

If the whole cell F&row is equal to #N/A and this is wrong because a range is a object, and you are asking if the range is equal to a text (#N/A)

Comment: Could you explain why and how it´d do it better?

Comment: @Elbert Villarreal .text does work for the loop. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @BigBen okay, I see then thanks for the hint again(you helped me already today) and I will try this. Thanks a lot

Comment: hey @Djerun don't forget to set the right answer. Glad to help you.